# Incorporating MWPhotoBrowser into tab bar view controller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

I have an existing app with four tab bar view controllers. I am trying to view MWPhotoBrowser in one of those controllers. I have added MWPhotoBrowser as a subproject but, despite all my searching, cannot work out how to incorporate it in my project. Any assistance would be much appreciated.